# Can't access public page properties in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I usually create public properties in my webforms pages such as CustomerID and then in my code behind when trying to open up a js window I would be able to retrieve that property using server tags such as:

```
<%= CustomerId%>
```

I could have sworn this used to work when I used VB.NET back in the day. Is this a VB.NET only thing?

I am declaring my public property at the top of the code-behind like this:

```
public int CustomerId
{
    get { return (int)(ViewState["CustomerId"] ?? Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"])); }
    set { ViewState["CustomerId"] = value; }
}
```

In the aspx page I am trying to do something like this in JavaScript:

```
url = "/CustomerDetailId=<%=CustomerId%>";
```

Comment: In code behind why you want to access the property using server tags but not directly?

Comment: Please post more code, we need more context.

Comment: I added more detail, please see above.

Comment: Your code should work. Are you getting any exception? or compile time errors?

Comment: Errr... long night sorry the intellisense threw me off. Thanks guys! it works!